# Placeholder hint while typing in EditText in Android

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` field and the user may only input six digits. When the `EditText` is focused, it should hint the user that he can only input six digits.

The idea is to display the remaining digits in gray, like this:

[image: Hint for remaining digits]

When the user inputs a digit, then it appears like this:

[image: Hint for remaining digits]

(The red vertical bar represents the cursor.)

The cursor should not be positioned behind its current position in both images; the gray digits should only be visible, and should not be selectable.

So in fact I want to set a placeholder text, but retain a part of the placeholder text whilst the user is typing.

I read about the `TextInputLayout` class from the Design Support library, but I don't know how I can achieve abovementioned idea.

How to do this?

Comment: Did you achieve this behavior? I'm about no selection of grey symbols, no cursor position on them. Thx for the answer

Answer (score 3):

I will give you only the idea, so implementation is up to you. Create your TextWatcher, in

```
onTextChanged()
```

Count how many digits user wrote and depending on this number create string padded with zeros. After it, make zeros be of different color

```
Spannable textWithTintedZeros = new SpannableString(paddedString);
textWithTintedZeros.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(yourGrey), firstZeroIndex, length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editText.setText(textWithTintedZeros);
```

And at last set selection to be before zeros with

```
editText.setSelection(indexBeforeFirstZero);
```

Don't forget also to block changing cursor position. I think can be done with

```
View.OnKeyListener
```

Comment: I'm going to try this. Note that when we set the text of the `EditText` *inside* the `onTextChanged()` using `setText()`, the `onTextChanged()` method is called recursively.

Comment: @MCEmperor yeah, flag helps if (!inEdit) { inEdit = true; ... inEdit = false; }

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about exactly the same. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could add over the edittext a TextView with gravity right. Then in the listener of edittext (ontextchanged) modify that TextView.

I don't know if you can do it with only EditText.